# Having issues with ternary operator

Tags: c#

I am trying to get back specific data from a ef query ,but I am having issues with my ternary operator

```
PlumbingSuperintendent = prj.JobInformation.Subdivision.AORs
.Where(x => 
    x.AOR_Contact_Type_ID == "SI" && x.Service_Type == "PLUMBING" && x.Effective_End_Date != null
    ? (x.Effective_End_Date > DateTime.Now)
    : !x.Effective_End_Date.HasValue && x.IsPrimary
)
.Select(x => x.Employee.Employee_FName + " " + x.Employee.Employee_LName).FirstOrDefault(),
```

what I am wanting to do if the effective end date is not null give me the records where effectice end date is greater than today. if not then give me the record with effective end date as null. For some reason this isn't working

Comment: Please provide [mcve] and a concrete input, real output and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create this condition with the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).

```
(x.Effective_End_Date ?? DateTime.Now) >= DateTime.Now
```

You may need to assign `DateTime.Now` to a variable as using it twice like this may not have exactly the same value.

Comment: that was close so it grabbed the one that had a date in the end date greater than today but what it didn't grab is all the rest that null values

Comment: that was correct sorry I didn't put the >= that worked exactly how I expected I get why you need to = if its greater than then it won't be equal to the datetimenow so that null record wont be picked up very nice man thank you